# Python variable assignment confusion

Tags: python

Why is it that when I do the following:

```
x = y = {}
```

Everytime I modify, x like `x[1] = 5`, I also end up modifying y and vice versa?

Comment: Hint: You expect "assignment by value", but what actually happens is "assignment by reference".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You assign the names `x` and `y` to be pointing to one and the same dictionary, what behaviour would you expect?

If you want them to point to *different* dictionaries, use

```
x = {}
y = {}
```

or

```
x,y = {},{}
```

Comment: @Agos: Sometimes, a rhetorical question is an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Because x and y references the same dictionary.

What happens under the hood:

```
-----   ------- 
| x | = | ref |----- 
-----   -------    |
                   v
                 ------
                 | {} |
                 ------
                   ^
-----   -------    |
| y | = | ref |-----
-----   -------
```

Read about mutable and immutable data:

- http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-immutable
- http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-mutable

Answer (score 1):

That is how references works. With `x = y = {}`, there are two reference variables, but they're both pointing to the same object. With `x[1] = 5`, you're not really modifying `x` itself, but rather, the object referred to by `x`. This is the same object referred to by `y`, unless you set `x` and/or `y` to refer to new objects.

#### See also

- [Wikipedia/Reference (computer science)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28computer_science%29)

Answer (score 1):

Variables on Python don't work like "boxes" (where you put objects), but as "labels" (where you assign names to objects).

So when you do:

```
x = y = {}
```

You are really saying to Python:

> I want to call *{}* as *x* and *y*.

Another way to understand this is that the *{}* syntax is just a shortcut for *dict()*, which simply returns a new *Dict* object. So another way to see would be:

```
x = y = dict()
```

This returns just **one** dict object, and assigns two names to it (*x* and *y*).

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers say, the original gotcha happens because you're assigning a reference. The next level of confusion is when you do something like this:

```
a = [[1]]
b = a[:] # You might think [:] will protect you from the original gotcha.
a[0][0] = 2
print b[0][0] # It's 2...why did this change?
```

It changed because the a[:] slice is actually copying a reference to a[0]. In other words, even though a and b refer to different lists because you used [:], the first element in each is referring to the same list. It's the original problem in a new form. The correct approach here is to do

```
import copy
a = [[1]]
b = copy.deepcopy(a)
a[0][0] = 2
print b[0][0] # 1
```